# is there a whatif switch for msbuild command line?

Tags: msbuild

I have a **msbuild** command line running on my build server. It is deploying after build with the switch `/p:DeployOnBuild=true`

Is there a switch like `whatif` for **msbuild** on deploy?

Comment: Please, clarify your question. What do you mean by *like `whatif`*?

Comment: @Alexander msdeploy.exe -whatif

Comment: Do you want to get a report of the package deploying, rather than deploying the package?

Comment: Voting to close as "unclear what you're asking", please state your expectation or describe the problem you are having / want to solve.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I want the report of the package deploying. msdeploy has whatif switch so that it will simulate the deployment before an actual deploy. I can't seem to find similar feature for msbuild when using /p:DeployOnBuild=true

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to implement the issue within continious integration.

#### Custom MSBuild task

You could create your own task that implements [`ITask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.framework.itask?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface. You could just derive your task from the helper class [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.utilities.task?view=netframework-4.7.2) and override its `Execute()` method. This solution is most flexible. So, it is possible to pass additional parameters from command line to deploing process or hardcode them in dependence on build configuration.

Then add the task to your project:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <!-- Register the custom task -->
    <UsingTask TaskName="TaskNamespace.MyTask" AssemblyFile="path\to\task\assembly.dll"/>

    <!-- Define something -->

    <!-- Set properties for Debug configuration -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">
        <WhatIf>true</WhatIf>
        <!-- Set another properties -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Set properties for Release configuration -->
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
        <WhatIf>false</WhatIf>
        <!-- Set another properties -->
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="MyTarget">  
        <MyTask OnlyReport="$(WhatIf)"/>  
    </Target>  
</Project>
```

See detailed indormation in the [Task Writing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/task-writing) article.

#### Different commands

It is possible to build your project and create a web package using `msbuild`, then create report of the package deploying using `msdeploy` or *.deploy.cmd* file. For example

```
msbuild "MySolution.sln" /t:MyProject /p:Configuration="Release" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="Local Package"
"path\to\MyProject.deploy.cmd" /T /M:"http://my-server.loc/MsDeployAgentService" /A:NTLM -allowUntrusted
```

The first command builds your web application project and creates local web deploy package. Note, it requires *Local Package* publication profile in your solution file.

The second line calls `msdeploy.exe` with the `–whatif` flag. Also it is possible to use `msdeploy.exe` directly. To get detailed information see [Deploying Web Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages).

#### Automating Web Package Deployment

Previous way could be automated using [`<Exec>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task) task of MSBuild. For example

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DeployMode>T</DeployMode>
    <DeployMode Condition=" '$(Configuration)'=='Release' ">Y</DeployMode>
    <DestinationServer>http://my-server.loc</DestinationServer>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="PublishWebPackages">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <DeployCommand>
          "path\to\MyProject.deploy.cmd" /$(DeployMode) /M:$(DestinationServer)/MsDeployAgentService /A:NTLM
        </DeployCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(DeployCommand)"/>
</Target>
```

You could also pass values of `DeployMode` and `DestinationServer` through `msbuild` command `/p:` switches.